# Progress dialog spinning wheel stops while loading

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am using the code for showing progress bar with spinning wheel in `asyn` task as below

```
class Startsyntask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
    {
         ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Myclass.this);
         protected void onPreExecute() 
         {
             dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
             dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
             dialog.setCancelable(false);
             dialog.show();
         }

         @Override
         protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) 
         {

            // my code to download the contents from the Server ( approx 230 mb in size)

            return null;    
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) 
         {      
             dialog.dismiss();
         }
    }
```

but the spinner shows only for some time and the spinner freezes . I don't know where i am going wrong . I could not guess whether the progress in complete or not . I have searched for many related threads but i could not get the solution yet .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Use `DownloadManager` to download data of large size (230 mb in your case). Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

Comment: Does it crash? or just run slow and freeze?

Comment: Are you using Startsyntask.fetch()?

Comment: spinner gets freeze . no crashes . am using Startsyntask.execute()

Answer (score 0):

Does it freeze of disappears? 
If it freezes than my guess is that you main thread is stuck. You probably have a bug or the download is doing something wrong.

Comment: yes actually the spinner gets freeze . Is this because of screen-lock ?

Comment: No, It shouldn't be related but you can sure test it by disabling the screen-lock and see what happens.  I thing that it's a loop some were in your code but you should test it.